# How to pass value captured in URL to middleman page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, dynamic, erb, middleman

I want to send emails to prospects with a link to highly customised middleman landing page.

I'll have a spreadsheet with the following columns:
name, company logo, position, etc.

I want my homepage to display the name of the recipient, the logo of the company and other values.

I know that I can create specific url that will pass those values to the landing page but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks a lot for guiding me :)